# Python abstraction

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

What is the best way to create a parent class that is able to define a set of methods that will be implemented by the base classes?

The problem comes when a class `A` requires 2 parameters for `method_X`, while class `B` requires 3 parameters for the same method.

How can I solve this issue?

```
class SuperClass:
    def method_X(self):
        ...

class A(SuperClass):
    def method_X(self, a, b):
        ...

class B(SuperClass):
    def method_X(self, a, b, c):
        ...
```

Comment: you can use [default arguments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/) to tackle this.

Comment: In short: don't. Your subclasses are breaking the contract set by the superclass.

Comment: Your code is not broken by itself (it's just not recommendable, since, at has been said, the subclasses shouldn't change the interface of methods they override), what is the issue that you are having? How are you planning to use your code?

Comment: This is one of the gripes in the infamous article [super harmful](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, do you break the contact when you use `*args` and `**kwargs` as parameters in the super class?

Comment: The whole thing about breaking the superclass interface is only relevant if you use inheritance for subtyping - if it's only for implementation then the point is moot (I don't mean one shouldn't think twice about it just that whether its a design error or not depends on the context)

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf: it still makes it impossible to use subclasses where the contract expected the superclass. You don't know what the method needs.

Comment: @wim that article is purely about multiple inheritance (and how `super()` appears to help in that situation but does not, in the author's opinion). There is no multiple inheritance here.

Comment: @wim this article about super being harmful is far from being a reference. Yes of course using cooperative super calls requires a proper design to work - just like a function needs to accept the current instance as first positional parameter to be usable as an instance method etc. Criticizing super for having some requirements is just plain stupid - use it when appropriate, dont use it when its obviously not the right tool, period.

Comment: I no longer read the super-harmful article as a criticism of `super`, but as a complement to Hettinger's super-super that emphasizes that you need to keep the signature of a super-using method consistent across classes.

Comment: The most important point to remember is that the fact that your function uses `super` is not just an implementation detail; it should be documented so that anyone overriding your method will know if they should (or should not) also use `super`.

Comment: Also, just because *you* are not using multiple inheritance doesn't mean someone else won't include your class in multiple-inheritance hierarchy. Don't assume `super` will call your statically defined base class next. (Corollary: don't user `super` simply as a way to avoid typing your base class's name.)

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to accomplish is a clear violation of [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Moreover, defining inconsistent interfaces for the same named methods is going to be messy and would severely limit duck typing. Still, if you want to go with it, I think using `kwargs` instead of named parameters would serve the purpose.

```
class SuperClass:
     def method_x(self, **kwargs):
         ...

class A(SuperClass):
     def method_x(self, **kwargs):
         if 'a' in kwargs:
             # Do something
```